# Getting error in AspectJ sample project

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

I am new to aspectJ. I am getting compilation errors in Aspect class. When I run the project, I am getting the compilation error. Please help me. Placing the code snippet and error obtained below:

Project structure:

[image]

MannersAspect.java

```java
package main.java.testaop;

public aspect MannersAspect {
    pointcut callSayMessage() :
        call(public static void HelloWorld.say*(..));
    before() : callSayMessage() {
        System.out.println("Good day!");
    }
    after() : callSayMessage() {
        System.out.println("Thank you!");
    }
}
```

HelloWorld.java

```java
package main.java.testaop;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void say(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
    public static void sayToPerson(String message, String name) {
        System.out.println(name + ", " + message);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>testaop</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>testaop</name>

    <dependencies>                            
        <dependency>       
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>    
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.4</version>          
        </dependency>                         
    </dependencies> 

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[2.5.1,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals><goal>compile</goal></goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action><ignore></ignore></action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[1.7,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals><goal>compile</goal></goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action><ignore></ignore></action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>                                                 
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>            
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>        
                <executions>                                         
                    <execution>                                      
                        <goals><goal>compile</goal></goals>                                     
                        <configuration>                              
                            <source>1.5</source>                     
                            <target>1.5</target>                     
                        </configuration>                             
                    </execution>                                     
                </executions>                                        
            </plugin>
            <plugin>                                                 
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>         
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>           
                <executions>                                         
                    <execution><goals><goal>java</goal></goals></execution>                                     
                </executions>                                        
                <configuration>                                      
                    <mainClass>main.java.testaop.HelloWorld</mainClass>            
                </configuration>                                     
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Error:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[ERROR] D:\workspacedummy\testaop\src\main\java\testaop\MannersAspect.java:[3,7] error: class, interface, or enum expected
[ERROR] D:\workspacedummy\testaop\src\main\java\testaop\MannersAspect.java:[4,51] error: class, interface, or enum expected
[ERROR] D:\workspacedummy\testaop\src\main\java\testaop\MannersAspect.java:[4,72] error: malformed floating point literal
[ERROR] D:\workspacedummy\testaop\src\main\java\testaop\MannersAspect.java:[5,4] error: class, interface, or enum expected
[ERROR] D:\workspacedummy\testaop\src\main\java\testaop\MannersAspect.java:[7,4] error: class, interface, or enum expected
[ERROR] D:\workspacedummy\testaop\src\main\java\testaop\MannersAspect.java:[10,4] error: class, interface, or enum expected
[INFO] 6 errors 
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project testaop: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created your aspect in Eclipse via "New" -> "Class" (thus the ".java" extension), but you should create it via "New" -> "Aspect" (then it will get an ".aj" extension).

P.S.: You do have AJDT (AspectJ Development Tools) installed in Eclipse, don't you? **;-)**

P.P.S.: Your Maven POM also contains a few problems, e.g. a runtime dependency on *AspectJ Runtime* 1.8.4, but the *AspectJ Maven Plugin* in the old version 1.5 uses *AspectJ Tools* 1.7.3. The current plugin version 1.7 uses *AspectJ Tools* 1.8.2 and can be upgraded to 1.8.4 via plugin dependency configuration, if necessary.